# Easy Way to Relate controls C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

I have a column of 10 textBoxs and another column of 10 labels. I want each `Label` to be the product between the `TextBox` at its left and a constant K (when the `TextBox` is completed).

I was thinking a way to write one function to handle all events of textBoxs `Leave`, and change the associated label.

Is there an easy way to know which `Label` to change without comparing the sender with each `TextBoxt`?

I hope I made myself understood, thanks in advance

Comment: Usually for showing controls in a grid/table layout, it's better to use `TableLayoutPanel` or `DataGridView`.  If you use `DataGridView` you can achieve the functionality easily using an expression column. If you use a `TableLayoutPanel`, you can use `GetRow`, `GetColumn`, `GetPositionFromControl`, `GetControlFromPosition` to find position of a control or find a control by position.

Comment: Also it's almost always better to use `Validating` event to validate `TextBox` data and get the value.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using TableLayoutPanel**

Use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview), add all the text boxes to the first column and all the labels to the second column. Then handle `Validating` event of all text boxes using a single event handler.

```
const int K = 10;
private void TextBoxes_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var txt = (TextBox)sender;
    if (int.TryParse(txt.Text, out int value))
    {
        var row = tableLayoutPanel1.GetRow(txt);
        var lbl = tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(1, row);
        lbl.Text = $"{value * K}";
    }
}
```

You can use `TableLayoutPanel` methods to find controls based on the position and also find position of a control using `GetRow`, `GetColumn`, `GetPositionFromControl`, `GetControlFromPosition`.

**Using DataGridView**

Another option would be using a `DataGridView` control bound to a `DataTable`. The `DataTable` can have an int column and an expression column.

```
const int K = 10;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("C1", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("C2", typeof(int), $"C1 * {K}");

    dt.Rows.Add(1);
    dt.Rows.Add(2);
    dt.Rows.Add(3);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

To learn about expression format take a look at [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a couple of arrays and do this:

```
var labels = new[] { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7, label8, label9, label10, };
var textBoxes = new[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6, textBox7, textBox8, textBox9, textBox10, };

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var textBox = textBoxes[i];
    var label = labels[i];
    textBox.Leave += (_s, _e) => label.Text = (double.Parse(textBox.Text) * 3.14159).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make new object that contained of 1 TextBox and 1 Lable
Write all of function and handler in this new object 
Use this new object in your project instead of standard TextBox and Lable
Each of them work separately and do not need to write add any control code to them

Answer (score 0):

give all of them a common class. create a javascript handler for it and use $(this) to access the particular textbox on event. to access label you could use .Closest() function.

Comment: It's a Windows Forms question.